# GWT(GXT 2.2.2) + Jetty = Ok. Glassfish = 404

Tags: gwt, glassfish, http-status-code-404

I installed: JDK 1.7.0_10, GWT 2.4, GXT 2.2.5, App Engine 1.7.0, Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2, Glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows-ml, WinXP SP3.

I created a new “Web Application project”. Run->Run As… -> Web application:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/Exp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

In that case I had:

Sending name to the server:

```
GWT User

Server replies:
Hello, GWT User!

I am running Google App Engine Development/1.7.0.
It looks like you are using:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.sample.Exp.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/exp/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Exp.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>services</param-name>
      <param-value/>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I compiled my application and copy “war” folder into glassfish docroot: E:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot\exp\

If I try to open the link: `http://localhost:8080/exp/Exp.html`
I have the error:

```
Sending name to the server:
GWT User

Server replies:
An error occurred while attempting to contact the server. 
Please check your network connection and try again.
```

The error is:

> com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 GlassFish v3 - Error
>   report
>
> ## HTTP
>   Status 404 -
>
> ---
>
> **type** Status
>   report
>
> **message**
>
> **description**The requested
>   resource () is not available.
>
> ---
>
> #### GlassFish Server Open Source
>   Edition 3.1.2.2

Comment: can you show mapping of web.xml file?

Comment: Why are you using war folder in url? put war content under exp folder direct or just rename war to exp. try http://localhost:8080/exp/Exp.html or http://localhost:8080/exp

Comment: @Bhumika it was a misprint in my post. Of course, I load a right html file, but server response is a 404 error.

Comment: Can you use firebug to monitor the rpc request post and identify the discrepancy in the url w.r.t to what is set up in web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying content to the root won't work. Try to build **war** file (not sure, but application's root could be also ok) and to place it to **autodeploy** folder. Here is the detailed [description](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/deployment/index.html#0.0.0.0.Deploying%20Applications%7Coutline) of deploy process. Please also check *Glassfish* logs, to be sure that application is deployed successfully.